# Generate SecKeyRef from base64 RSA public key

Tags: ios, security, encryption, rsa, ios-frameworks

I have looked at other answers on StackOverflow and I didn't find what I was looking for. 
I have a public RSA key in Base64 format generated by some other system. 
It is in x509 format and the encryption is 512 bits strong.

I need to create a SecKeyRef in order to use an encrypt some data and send back home. (for all purposes the public key is sent from the server side)

I can't find anything on the web that helps me in this situation, all other examples and answers by-pass the problem. I can't create a PEM or DER files or use any other 'tricks', **Base64 -> SecKeyRef** nothing less.

I know this is a hard one so thank you all for helping.

p.s this is for a framework and not an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this amazing GitHub project which helped me a **lot!**

https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA

I hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't the suitable answer for this question.